# Как создать свою оболочку андроид как (MIUI/EMUI/Oxygen OS/One UI)?

Tags: android

Начал изучать тему про сборку кастомных прошивок андроид. Уже как два года в этой теме.

Вот только никто еще не писал про это в англоязычных форумах, на русских форумах вообще ничего про это нету.

Являюсь джуном С++/Python/Java/Dart

Comment: если по простому, то берется исходный код андроид (а он open source проект) и исправляется. https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/

Comment: @pentiux это ясно. Вот только официальная документация поверхностно проходит по всему. Я например никак не смог найти элементарно подробную информацию про Notification panel или же статус бар простым языком

Comment: @KING, исходный код - вот ваша документация) если вы не можете в нем разобраться, то вам еще рановато думать о своей оболочке)

Comment: еще один вопрос. У меня ноут на гейвидия + амуде, и из-за этого траблы при установке линукса. Вот думаю накатить на виртуалку и там собирать прошивку, какие подводные камни есть в этом варианте?